# How do I make a promise resolve as an object in the view?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, ngresource

I'm trying to wrap a third party library to return an object that resolves into an object that can be displayed in the view, similar to how $resource() works. I'm aware that I can manually do .then() on the promise and then set the value, but I wanted the result to seamlessly return similar to how I can do:

```
this.Value = $resource("/someresource").get();
```

How would I change the below SomeThirdPartyFunction() to return an object that resolves in the view.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
angular.module('testApp', []).controller('TestController', function ($timeout, $q) {
    var TestController = this;
    var SomeThirdPartyFunction = function () {
        var Deferred = $q.defer();
        var Promise = Deferred.promise;

        $timeout(function () {
            Deferred.resolve("abcd");
        }, 3000);

        return Promise;
    };

    TestController.Value = SomeThirdPartyFunction();

    /* I don't want to do this:
    SomeThirdPartyFunction().then(function(Value) {
      TestController.Value = Value;
    });*/
});
```

And here's a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/HypQMkaqXmFZkvYZXFXf?p=preview

Every example I've seen using promises just wraps $http calls, but I haven't seen any examples of calling third party libraries that return promises that resolve into objects.

Comment: The $resource service only works when the data is an object or an array. It does not work with primitives such as the string in your example.

Comment: Yeah, I was just using the string as an example. My specific use is for an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [AngularJS document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource#$resource-returns):

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method
>   immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on
>   isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing
>   reference is populated with the actual data.

So instead of return a promise, you can do something like this:

```
  var SomeThirdPartyFunction = function() {
    var getAComplextObject = function() {
      return {
        number: 42,
        method: function() {
          return this.number + 1;
        }
      };
    };

    var returnValue = {};

    $timeout(function() {
      console.log("Resolved!");
      Object.assign(returnValue, getAComplextObject());
    }, 1000);

    return returnValue;
  };
```

You can wrap it in a promise and make the promise part of the return value, doing that you can make it thenable (aka a Promise)

Comment: How would this work if instead of 1234, I need to return a more complex object with methods on it. Do I need to manually loop through and copy each property/value?

Comment: You don't have to clone that object, just assign it to the returnValue, something like this `returnValue.Value = complex_Object`

Comment: Check an example from a fork of you plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/NaiGN25iWh0YBZdUozdE?p=preview

Comment: I don't want to change all my code to Object.Value.Property though. I want my views to be able to use Object.Property

Comment: So the tricky part is to use `Object.assign`, I have updated the example in my answer

Comment: Okay, got it. Thanks for your help. It doesn't look I this works for my specific use case, since my third party library will update first level values as well. i.e. ComplexObject.number += 5, after I've done the assignment. So there's no way I can see that change reflected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174847/discussion-between-lambo-jayapalan-and-lastr2d2).

Comment: Yep, but that should be a total different question.. the answer to you original question would be `return an empty object and then populate data to that object`, how to populate data with your user case should be another question..

Answer (score 1):

Under-the-hood, [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) uses [angular.copy](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.10/docs/api/ng/function/angular.copy):

```
function myResourceGet(params) {
    var emptyObj = {};
    emptyObj.$resolved = false;
    emptyObj.$promise = $http.get(url, {params:params})
      .then(function(response) {
        angular.copy(response.data, emptyObj);
    }).finally(function() {
        emptyObj.$resolved = true;
    });
    return emptyObj;
}
```

From the Docs:

> ### angular.copy Overview
>
> Creates a deep copy of `source`, which should be an object or an array.
>
> - If a destination is provided, all of its elements (for arrays) or properties (for objects) are deleted and then all elements/properties from the source are copied to it.

The $resource service only works when the data is an object or an array. It does not work with primitives such as a string or number.